# Is it possible to install Facebook Augmented traffic control on MAC machine?

Tags: network-traffic, bandwidth-throttling

I have referred this link https://github.com/facebook/augmented-traffic-control to configure the ATC. Please let me know if someone has configured the same on MAC machine.

Comment: Not a programming question - try [sf] ?

Comment: There is no `darwin` backend (i.e. it won't support mac). Have you experimented with the network link conditioner preference pane? It accomplishes a similar thing on OSX.

Comment: Thanks Petesh..My objective is to achieve the throttling over the multiple android test devices.. so i dont think Network Link Conditioner will work in that case. Please let me know if there is any other way to do this.